# div content doesn't animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

Hello i am using jquery to animate a box on the left to slide right to show the facebook link , the box slides fine but the text inside seems not to be affected by the jquery function , my code is :

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#social").mouseenter(function () {

        $("#social").animate({
            width: 50
        });

    });

    $("#social").mouseleave(function () {

        $("#social").animate({
            width: 20
        });

    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="social"><a href="xxxx.com">test</a></div>
```

The problem is whith the a href , it doesnt animate with the div , i tried to give the a href an id , still didnt work

Comment: How do you mean "doesn't animate with the `div`"? Can you maybe post a JSFiddle showing the problem?

Comment: you need your `<a href>` to also expand along with the div?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `e.preventdefault()`

```
$("#social").mouseenter(function () {
       e.preventdefault();
        $("#social").animate({
            width: 50
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your div has a specified width for it to animate, for example:

```
#social {
    width: 20px;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f2tuG/)**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but if you want the `<a>` to expand along with the `<div>`, just add a `display: inline-block;` and `width: 100%;` in your css:

```
#social a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vtf7u/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys i found the solution , i need to change the marginLeft so that it looks like the whole thing box with link was a bit hidden then shows

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#social").mouseenter(function(){


$("#social").animate({width:80});
$("#social").animate({marginLeft:'0px'});



     });

      $("#social").mouseleave(function(){


$("#social").animate({width:40});
$("#social").animate({marginLeft:'-10px'});



      });

       });
```